# ifelse command using colnames in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

> df1<-data.frame(c(0,0,0),c(0,1,0),c(1,0,0))
>
> names(df1)<-c("A","B","C")

```
  A B C
1 0 0 1
2 0 1 0
3 0 0 0
```

I would like to substitute the "1" values in df1 for the column names associated with those values, to create a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  A B C
1 0 0 C
2 0 B 0
3 0 0 0
```

I tried the following code, but it produced the incorrect dataframe (listed below):

> data.frame(ifelse(df==1,colnames(df),0))

```
  A B C
1 0 0 A
2 0 B 0
3 0 0 0
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `df1<-data.frame(c(0,0,0),c(0,1,0),c(1,0,0))
names(df1)<-c("A","B","C")` can be replaced by `df1<-data.frame(A=c(0,0,0),B=c(0,1,0),C=c(1,0,0))`, FYI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is happening is that `ifelse` is running once per column, and when it comes to replacing an element, it takes the nth element of `colnames`. But because `ifelse` is run on each column at a time, indexing `colnames` ends up matching to the row-index, not to the column-index. In order to get the right solution, ifelse needs to run on the row vectors, not on the column vectors.

Here is one solution, which uses the t (transpose) function.

```
t(ifelse(t(df1)==1,names(df1),0))
     A   B   C  
[1,] "0" "0" "C"
[2,] "0" "B" "0"
[3,] "0" "0" "0"
```

Comment: +1 - Also consider `ifelse(df1 == 1, colnames(df1)[col(df1)], "0")`